# Android - Notification while in Do Not Disturb and in Doze mode

Tags: android, android-notifications

I am having a hard time figuring out a solution for my fire alarm app. Which can create a notification even when a user's device is in Doze mode or do not disturb mode.

Any pointers or ideas would be helpful!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's much you can do, except checking if your app is allowed to override Do Not Disturb mode and if it is not, prompting the user to allow so.

To be able check whether your app overrides DND, check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50724078/how-to-get-override-do-not-disturb-settings-value).

Hope this helps. If you find any other way, please keep us updated.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The link is helpful! But still, I don't understand, what does it mean by "checking if your app is allowed to override Do Not Disturb mode"?

Comment: @MobileLearner Overriding means being allowed to send notifications even though DND is enabled. You can try this on your device by going into the system settings of an app, e.g. Telegram and then go to Notifications, select a notifications channel and enable Override Do not Disturb. When you then enable DND and the app posts a notification on that channel, it will still be posted.